What is the main point, moral, or lesson of "Watership Down"?
As an 80s child in the UK, my school book review was Watership Down. I expected an A but I was given a B+ with the feedback, “You missed the point”.
In my summary of the final battle, I wrote that Hazel was not triumphant, but had mixed feelings about having no choice but to take a life to save his people. Then he passed of old age, watching his grandchildren, and knowing children of his grandchildren cemented the future success. I thought that was the point of the book, we should avoid conflict but dig deep when no other choice was offered.
Today, 40 years later, my teacher’s grade and comment still pop into my head. Was Efrafa a representation of a historical battle that I missed entirely due to my young age?

I've edited your question into what I think you're asking, and removed a lot of the less-relevant stuff. Please could you check and see if I've accurately represented your question? The last line of your original post was "Was Efrafa a simile for a historical battle that I missed entirely due to my young age?" - a community can't be a simile for a battle, but I assume you're asking whether the final battle with Efrafa was based on some historical battle, so I've edited to put that as the title of your post.

It was the teachers comment primarily, the Efrafa scenario was the biggest event, so I’m assuming this was her reasoning. As I’m  without a clear direction, I’m open to being utterly incorrect with my assumption.

I've updated the title to correspond to how I understand the question, but feel free to revise if you think I haven't got it right.

When you say, "my teacher's grade and comment still pop into my head", I think it is time to let go of that, because (I think) it was your teacher who missed the "point", whatever it was.
According to the author, these events were made up off the top of his head, to entertain his two children while going on long drives. There was not supposed to be some deeper meaning to it all, other than entertaining the kids along the way.
Now, when each reader and each teacher finds some deeper meaning to it, then each interpretation is as valid as the other. In that sense the teacher has some interpretation (which was not told to you), while you have some interpretation which you wrote down in that review. Both are valid (as long as it makes sense) and there is no "point" to miss.
I am sure your valid review made sense (hence you got B+), it just did not match the interpretation your teacher wanted.
In case there are 3-4 answers here, each giving a new interpretation, then there is no way to know which of those were what your teacher wanted. Writing all that interpretative thinking might have still got you the same B+ with the same comment.
My summary : There is no "point" to miss.
My unsolicited advice : Let go and move on.
My references for this thinking :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watership_Down#Origin_and_publication_history

The story began as tales that Richard Adams told his young daughters
Juliet and Rosamund during long car journeys. He recounted in 2007
that he "began telling the story of the rabbits … improvised off the
top of [his] head, as [they] were driving along". The daughters
insisted he write it down—"they were very, very persistent". After
some delay he began writing in the evenings and completed it 18 months
later. The book is dedicated to the two girls.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watership_Down#Religious_symbolism

When asked in a 2007 BBC Radio interview about the religious symbolism
in the novel, Adams said the story was "nothing like that at all". He
said the rabbits in Watership Down did not worship; however, "they
believed passionately in El-ahrairah." Adams explained that he meant
the book to be "only a made-up story … in no sense an allegory or
parable or any kind of political myth. I simply wrote down a story I
told to my little girls." Instead, he explained, the "let-in"
religious stories of El-ahrairah were meant more as legendary tales,
similar to a rabbit Robin Hood, and these stories were interspersed
throughout the book as humorous interjections to the often "grim"
tales of the "real story".


Isn't the point of essays at that level to make some logical, reasoned argument, and back it up with quotes/facts/ideas from the text — and not necessarily to come up with a ‘right’ answer?  (Ideally, you should get high marks for presenting an argument with with the teacher completely disagrees, provided it's well argued, justified, and supported.)

At least when Author explicitly says (eg) "My novel is about the hardships of middle eastern women" and reviewer says (eg) "Moral is to develop Inter Planetary Communications" , then teacher might claim missing the Point. Even then , when reviewer logically backs it up with materiel from the text , marks should be given. Present Case is where Author explicitly says that there is no moral , @gidds , then there is no way to miss the "Non Existent Point" to match with what teacher wanted. The "B+" indicates logical validity , hence it should have been the "A" which reviewer wanted. Too late now !
